# Is there a way to set row height to match wrapped text height?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I note there's a way to automatically set column width with autoResizeColumn() but there doesn't appear to be a comparable way to automatically set row height to match the height displayed by setWrap()'d text. How would I script this to determine the height of a given wrapped cell so that I can use it with setRowHeight()? Is there a way to see how the string value of a cell wraps? I believe getRowHeight() returns the "set" height, not the displayed height.

I'm trying to do something comparable to this for Excel: http://excelribbon.tips.net/T010735_Automatic_Row_Height_for_Wrapped_Text.html

In fact, the problem manifests itself when sheets are exported as Excel.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a bug in the export conversion, not something that should be none in a script. That said, it might be possible to approximately determine the row hight by looking at the contents of the row, the font size, and column width, and wrap policy. Won't give you an exact hight, but should be able to get close enough. If you size conservatively, worse case is you may have an extra line of empty space.

There are some potential issues that you might have to work around in doing so (see https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4187)

Comment: Thanks, Steve. That issue basically confirms the problem in that they are not properly reporting row height and cell width via the API. If there were, I bet export conversion would work properly too.